# How to run dbt from Crontab in Ubuntu?

Tags: cron, dbt

I want to create a Cron job that runs DBT https://www.getdbt.com/ on the schedule. Normally, I run it in a virtual environment with `dbt run` command in a dbt folder.

I've created the cron job in crontab

```
12 11 * * * cd ~/path/to/dbt-folder && ~/path/to/.venv/python dbt run
```

And it's not working.

Can someone provide some help on how to configure DBT job in crontab?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the dbt binary directly, your cron should look something like this

```
12 11 * * * cd ~/path/to/dbt-folder && ~/path/to/.venv/bin/dbt run
```